# bash script to compare two files and delete lines in target file

Tags: bash

Two files are to be compared, line by line.  The first file as a list of strings to be searched, one per line.

```
office@meridian.az
astana@globalair.com
```

While the second has lines of strings where the values may appear

```
0   1   Romania bilete@paravion.ro
0   1   Azerbaidjan office@meridian.az
0   1   Spain   bras@aerotravel.es
0   1   Uzbekistan  astana@globalair.com
```

What is a concise script that allows to delete lines of the second file where the line includes the full string of a line in the first file?

Comment: than answer applies to entire lines if I am not mistaken?

Comment: right, use the second answer (sorted by votes). It's basically `grep -Fvf file1 file2`